# PHP File upload working but file missing

Tags: php, file-upload

I don't understand why the $_FILES object seems to exist and tells me the file path, but then when I look for the file it doesn't exist (note upload_tmp_dir is not set in php.ini so it should be going to the /tmp directory, but I do not see it there at the command line.)

The response I get at the console:

```
Array
(
    [upload_file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Capture.PNG
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phplFIm0b
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 12612
        )

)
file upload failed
```

The interface page:

```
<?php
    include 'php/assets.php';
    $sel_str = "selected='selected'";
    $default_page_size = 100;
    $num_assets = count_assets();
    $num_pages = ceil($num_assets/$default_page_size);
?>
<html>
    <header>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sacs.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="css/sacs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </header>
    <body>
        <!--Popup Modal-->
        <div id="modal" class="modal fade">
        </div>
        <!--Main Body Container-->
        <div class="container">
            <!--Navbar Controls-->
            <div class="row">
                <?php $_POST["PAGE"] = "MM"; ?>
                <?php include 'php/navbar.php'; ?>
            </div>

            <!--Sort/Filter Controls-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Upload Metric Events</div>
                        <div id="metric_upload_panel" class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="file_path" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Uploading Metric..." aria-label="Search for...">
                                    </input>
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                            <input id="fileinput" type="file" hidden>Select File</input>
                                        </label>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
<script>
    function uploadFile(file){
        var url = 'php/upload_metric_post.php';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // Every thing ok, file uploaded
                console.log(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
            }
        };
        fd.append("upload_file", file);
        xhr.send(fd);
    }

    var fileinput = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    fileinput.addEventListener('change', function () {
        var file = this.files[0];
        uploadFile(file); // call the function to upload the file
        //alert(response);
    }, false);
```

The post file:

```
<?php
$uploadedFile = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'];
$destination = "product_$newname";
//echo sys_get_temp_dir();
print_r($_FILES);
if(file_exists($uploadedFile)){
    echo "file uploaded to temp dir";
}else{
    echo "file upload failed";
    exit();
}

if(move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile, $destination)){
    echo "upload complete";
}else{
    echo "move_uploaded_file failed";
    exit();
}


    if (isset($_FILES['upload_file'])) {
        if(file_exists($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'])){
            echo "file uploaded to temp dir";
        }else{
            echo "file upload failed";
            exit();
        }
        $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/DEV/gui/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['upload_file']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
            echo $_FILES['upload_file']['name']. " OK";
        } else {
            echo "Cannot Move File From ". $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']. " TO ". $uploadfile;
        }
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "No files uploaded ...";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/DEV/gui';` is missing a trailing slash. Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45744420/1

Comment: Fixed, but the code doesn't make it that far yet.

Comment: so check for folder permissions

Comment: drwxrwxrwt.   8 root    root  4096 Aug 17 16:32 tmp

Comment: Error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: New info (what does it mean, how can I fix): Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/phpsDlSCh) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/html/:./:/web/cas/SACS/SubmittedMetrics/) in /web/cas/SACS/DEV/gui/php/upload_metric_post.php on line 9

Comment: You also need to make sure the folder exists, this `$destination = "product_$newname";` suggests you're trying to create a new one and I don't know what or where `$newname` comes from. Edit: well there you go ;-) as per my comment here.

Comment: Yeah, it's not getting there yet anyway. I don't really know what the error means or how to fix. I suspect I should as /tmp directory to httpd.conf add an allowable path? I am a little lost... setting up the environment is always the hardest part of programming for me.

Comment: modify your php.ini http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: Thanks soundz... it works! I do not really understand what this is, why I had to assign /tmp path to it or how openbasedir works and it doesn't appear obvious... so I would recommend adding the answer... or do you think I should delete this?